# Guardar datos usando InMemoryBackendService en Angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Estoy tratando de guardar datos usando este modulo de **Angular 2**

*in-memory-users.ts*

```
export class InMemoryDataService {
      createDb() {
      let usuarios = [
      { id: 5 , nombre: "juan" , nick: "kevinlll4" , email: "exxx@hotmail.com"},
      { id: 6 , nombre: "juadn" , nick: "kevinlll4" , email: "exxx@hotmail.com"},
      { id: 7 , nombre: "juadn" , nick: "kevinlll4" , email: "eexxx@hotmail.com"},
      { id: 8 , nombre: "juan" , nick: "kevinlll4" , email: "exxx@hotmail.com"}
    ];
        return {usuarios};

      }
    }
```

Método con el cual guardo nuevos usuarios.

*user.service.ts*

```
private post(user: User): Promise<User> {
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  return this.http
             .post(this.usersUrl, JSON.stringify(user), {headers: headers})
             .toPromise()
             .then(res => res.json().data)
             .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Veo que cuando adiciono el usuario aparece agregado en la lista, pero cuando *actualizo* la página, es como si no se hubiese agregado.

Comment: Me parece que el problema viene porque estas usando una colección en memoria para obtener la lista y una petición http para crear un usuario nuevo. Esos son dos almacenes diferentes por lo que cuando insertas el almacén en memoria no se ha actualizado. Debes decidir cual de los dos quieres usar y desechar el otro.

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?, ¿Estás usando bindings?